# Using Views to filter the content based on the current month

Tags: views

I am building a site, using Views, that needs to filter the content for each month. I have created a date field on the custom content type, and I made a publish start and end date fields.

I need the view to change the content at the start of the new month. Can anyone please explain how to make a view only display content based on the current month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest versions of Views, you can use a date argument to do this.  For example, you could select the node post date as a date to use with the argument, and then if you passed 2011-12 as the argument, it would limit the display to only nodes posted in December 2011.  You can use any ISO date for this, too, so P1M, which means a period of 1 month, would create an argument for the current month.  Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 for an indepth explanation of a lot of different ISO date formats.  All should work here, the only one you have to be careful of is the interval format; with drupal you need to use -- instead of / to separate them for hopefully obvious reasons.

If, however, you are wanting to group or aggregate your content by month, check out http://drupal.org/node/388140.

Comment: Hey thanks for being such a help jimajamma. Can you clarify what I am doing here. So in the view I go to contextual filters and select publish date (a custom field I created on a content type to specify the month to publish the article)...

Comment: I can't use the post date because I plan to create the articles ahead of time and have them ready when the month changes... all updates automatic. Now I created two posts one with the publish date of december 2011 and one with the date of jan 2012... they both are showing. I tried to filter the content by the publish date and got nothing. I am confised as to how to make this filter correctly and push and pull content.

Comment: I also didn't see any place to work out an argument... I need some help with this.

Comment: Where do I attach this argument? (P1M) This is exactly what I need but don't see where to implement.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still looking for a way to figure out this one.

1. Open your views UI
2. Look to Page Settings -> Path
3. Set the Path like this: "news/%". You can use any word you like, obviously.
4. Go to "Advanced Tab" -> Contextual Filter -> Created Year. Use Defaults

Now you can filter your nodes by passing additional argument to your URL like this:

news/2015

news/2014

Thats all